# Summary Statistics for different categories using hive

Tags: sql, hive

I have below two hive tables called a and b. I need to create descriptive summary stats for it.
Now I want to calculate the summary statistics like below:

Expected output

```
        Sum of Amount  Count   Sum of Fraud Amount  Count of Fraud
0-100       120          2               70                1
100-500     610          3              410                2
>500        1300         2              700                1
```

Where I need Sum of Amount and count by categories mentioned like 0-100, 100-500 and >500.
Second i also need Sum of fraud amount (Where Fraud = 1) and count of frauds.I need to left join to get fraud column to calculate it.

e.g Category 0-100, The sum of amount is 120 (50+70) and count is 2. And Sum of fraud amount is 70 where fraud is 1. Similarly for others i need to calculate.

Table a

```
ID  Amount    Date
1   110     01-01-2020
2   200     02-01-2020
3   50      03-01-2020
4   600     04-01-2020
5   700     05-01-2020
6   70      06-01-2020
7   300     07-01-2020
```

Table b

```
ID  Fraud
1    1
2    0
3    0
4    0
5    1
6    1
7    0
```

My Approach where i got overall count and Amount sum but i need category wise like, 0-100, 100-500, and >500

```
select sum(a.Amount), Count(*), count(b.Fraud)
from sample.data a
left join (select id, fraud from sample.label) b
on a.id = b.id
where date between "2020-01-01" and "2020-01-07"
group by fraud;
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you just need to aggregate by a `case` expression:

```
select (case when d.amount <= 100 then '0-100'
             when d.amount <= 500 then '101-500'
             else '> 500'
        end) as grp,
       sum(d.Amount), Count(*), sum(l.Fraud)
from sample.data d left join
     sample.label l
     on a.id = l.id
where d.date between '2020-01-01' and '2020-01-07'
group by (case when d.amount <= 100 then '0-100'
               when d.amount <= 500 then '101-500'
               else '> 500'
          end);
```

Comment: I'm getting error ....Error while compiling statement failed parseexception line 12:7 missing EOF at 'sum' near 'grp'.. Do you know how to resolve it.

Comment: With New code changes got Error While Compiling statement: FAILED: Semantic Exception[ Error 10004]: line 17:9 invalid table alias or column reference 'grp':(possible column names are d.ID, d.amount, d.Date,  l.ID, l.Fraud)